# How to send requests through nginx for rate limiting ( throttle) per second?

Tags: node.js, nginx, superagent, throttling

I have script i node.js that makes requests to other api s. This script can run locally, on server, anywhere, it does not matter. The servers have limitations on requests per second. How can i send the reqs through NGINX?How to set nginx for it? should i change the urls, for example if i want to send requests to facebook, i need to configure specific nginx path like `localhost:8081/facebooklocal`, for it, and send reqs to nginxs `localhost:8081/facebooklocal`, and set req limits for it? Which way is better?
 Also i need, to limit reqs with specific parameter in it*
There are a lot of tutorials about incoming requests, but i am asking about outcoming requests (from locally running server to some API s).

How to redirect requests to localhost:8085/api to theremotesite/api ?

Comment: What have you tried? https://serverfault.com/a/817165/334725 might have your answer

Comment: @tavnab  now i am searching for right way. I have not tried anything yet. Trying to understand right way to do this. Is it right, that i need to send requests from app (running locally) to special configured (with limitis) nginx path? or maybe there are another ways?

Comment: NGINX can be used as a forward proxy (what you're describing here), and there are some tutorials online on how to do that ([here's one](https://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server)), but it doesn't support proxying HTTPS, so if you need to do that, it's not the right choice for you. You can also use [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org), which is designed to be a forward proxy and supports [delay pools](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DelayPools) for throttling. Or you can do the throttling in your own client code (if you have access to it). Try one of these options out.

Comment: @tavnab, Thank you  a lot, i have choosed NGINX, it fits awesome! Dear, maybe you can say or link, how to set limi req in nginx for requests with specific query or POST parameters in body?